# under which account does event receiver code run?

Tags: event-receivers

I would like to know under which account does event receiver code run?

Also suppose event receiver is ran on item added event that creates an item in another list. Then what will be the created by value foe that new item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event receiver will run under the account of the user who has triggered that event, like say ItemAdding will run under the account of the user who has added the item etc. You can use 
`properties.CurrentUserId` to get the id of the user under whose context code will be executed.

See this [blog](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/12/27/event-receivers-sharepoint-2010/) for more details

Comment: can you also update your answer to mention the processname under which the event receiver runs (is it the w3p?), please

Comment: Is it the w3p or the owstimer

Comment: @variable it will run under w3wp process

Comment: I have read that Synchronous event receivers (adding) run on the w3p.exe and the Asynchronous event receivers (added) run on OWSTimer.exe, can you confirm this please?

Comment: Item adding and item added both run under w3wp process. If you want to verify this you can create one and try debugging using w3wp process.

Comment: afaik, itemAdded etc. eventReceivers works under owstimer.exe